# Greatest common divisor of rational polynomials in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

> Consider the ring $\mathbb Q[x]$.
>
> (a) Suppose that $a(x) = (x+1)^3(x-1)^4(x+2)$ and $b(x) = (x+1)^2(x+2)^3(x-3)^4$.  What is the $\gcd (a(x),b(x))$?
>
> (b) Suppose that $c(x) =  (x^2-1)^4(x^2+3x+2)$.  What is the $\gcd(a(x),c(x))$?

My thoughts:There may be a short cut to figuring it out based of the degrees of each product of $a(x)$, $b(x)$, $c(x)$ or do you multiply them out and divide?

Comment: Why are you multiplying anything?

Comment: the preceeding chapter was finding the GCD of polynomials in a certain modular say Z(mod 7). So i didnt know if I needed all of the functions written fully out instead of in the form we have in the problem.  Or am I just thinking to deep into it?

Comment: If you know how to compute GCDs of integers using their prime factorization you should know how to compute the GCD of polynomials using their factorization into irreducibles - the process is the exact same.

Comment: In integers you have Euclidean algorithm; one can also find gcd by factoring the two  numbers completely into primes; Here you have been given two polynomials factorized completely; follow the same procedure as in integers.

Comment: I just learned the process today.  Still a little bit hazy on the subject. Can you shed any insight on this concept?

Comment: the only way I know how to find the GCD of polynomials is just factoring them completely out and dividing (pretty much the euclidean algorithm)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\ $ If $\,p\,$ is a prime then $\,\gcd(pa,b) = p\gcd(a,b/p)\,$ if $\,p\mid b\,$ else $\,\gcd(a,b)$

Use this recursively as $\,p\,$ ranges over all the primes factors of $\,a(x),\,$ viz. $\,x\!-\!1,\ x\!+\!1,\ x+2,\ $ to compute the required gcds with $\,a(x).$

Alternatively use $\ \gcd(p^i f, p^j g) = p^{\min(i,j)}\gcd(f,g)\ $ if $\ p\nmid f,g$

Note $\,x^2-1 = (x-1)(x+1)\,$ and $\,x^2+3x+2 = (x+1)(x+2),\,$ or else use the factor theorem, i.e. $\,x-k\mid f(x)\iff f(k)=0.$

Comment: thank you I just am having a hard time applying it.  Is the key focusing on the exponents?

Comment: Yes, if you do full prime factorizations then taking the gcds is equivalent to taking the min of the corresponding exponents - just like for integer gcds. The above pulls out the prime factors of the gcd one prime at a time.

Comment: so am I right in saying that the GCD of a(x) and b(x) is (x+1)^2(x+2)?

Comment: @D-Man Yes, that is correct. Similarly for $\,c(x)\,$ using the prime factorizations I listed.

Comment: So in technical terms just using the definition of prime factors and what not summerize why we are able to use that logic on this problem... just to better my understanding of the material

Comment: It is a consequence of the *existence* and *uniquness* of prime factorizations, i.e. $\,\Bbb Q[x]\,$ is a UFD (since it has a Euclidean algorithm).